# How can I stop ReSharper from putting blank lines around some of my MSpec tests?

Tags: resharper, mspec

When I write code similar to this, ReSharper arranges my code layout nicely, until one of my tests (It should_...) needs to be wrapped onto a second line. Suddenly ReSharper then puts a blank line above and below the test, like this:

```
It should_have_the_expected_target_position = () => Focuser.CurrentStatus.TargetPositionInSteps.ShouldEqual(0);
It should_be_moving = () => Focuser.CurrentStatus.Moving.ShouldBeTrue();
It should_not_be_homing = () => Focuser.CurrentStatus.Homing.ShouldBeFalse();
It should_be_homed = () => Focuser.CurrentStatus.Homed.ShouldBeTrue();

It should_have_a_temperature_probe_attached =
    () => Focuser.CurrentStatus.TemperatureProbeDetected.ShouldBeTrue();

It should_not_have_remote_io = () => Focuser.CurrentStatus.RemoteInOutControllerDetected.ShouldBeFalse();
It should_not_have_a_hand_controller = () => Focuser.CurrentStatus.HandControllerDetected.ShouldBeFalse();
```

That looks kind of 'unclean' to my eyes. How can I eliminate the blank lines? I'd prefer the final result to look like this:

```
It should_have_the_expected_target_position = () => Focuser.CurrentStatus.TargetPositionInSteps.ShouldEqual(0);
It should_be_moving = () => Focuser.CurrentStatus.Moving.ShouldBeTrue();
It should_not_be_homing = () => Focuser.CurrentStatus.Homing.ShouldBeFalse();
It should_be_homed = () => Focuser.CurrentStatus.Homed.ShouldBeTrue();
It should_have_a_temperature_probe_attached =
    () => Focuser.CurrentStatus.TemperatureProbeDetected.ShouldBeTrue();
It should_not_have_remote_io = () => Focuser.CurrentStatus.RemoteInOutControllerDetected.ShouldBeFalse();
It should_not_have_a_hand_controller = () => Focuser.CurrentStatus.HandControllerDetected.ShouldBeFalse();
```

I'm using ReSharper 8.1.

Comment: Do you generally like the line wrapping? I usually turn it off in favor of manual wrapping... might avoid the problem all together.

Comment: I do rely on the line wrapping quite a lot, but I have my margins set quite wide so it doesn't happen very often. I just can't see why R# adds those extra blank lines just because of a line wrap. DO you know which setting controls it?

Comment: I'm not able to look it up at the moment... might take me a while, hopefully somebody else comes along ;) ReSharper's formatting options need search.